# how to update selected radio button in flutter using getx

Tags: flutter, controller, radio-button, state-management, flutter-getx

I am using Flutter with GetX plugin and I have three radio buttons inside statelesswidget but the radio button doesn't changed to selected when user click on it so my question is how I can update the selected radio using GetX plugin. here is my code

```
                  activeColor: mainColor1,
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  // checkColor: Colors.white,
                  value: isSelected,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    print('=====');
                    setState(() {
                      isSelected = value;
                      widget.onPress(value);
                    });
            })
          ),
```

and here is my controller side

```
  changeStatus(String select, bool condition) {

    if (condition) {
      selected.add(select);
    } else {
      selected.remove(select);
    }
    print(selected.length);
    update();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize your controller like this:

```
final Controller _controller = Get.put(Controller());
```

call your method like this in `onChanged`:

```
_controller.your method
```

& put the whole dropdown widget in:

```
Obx(()=>DropdownButton)
```